# Array augmentation problem in Java

Tags: java, arrays, outofrangeexception

I have here a program that is supposed to begin with an array of length 1, allow the user to make an entry into the array, and then double the size of the array with each entry the user makes to avoid an *java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException* error. The way the code is written below, the computer skips *else if* after the second user entry and goes straight for *Sorry, database is full*. If I add *newRecords = records* in the first *else if* block, I get the *java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException* error.

```
public class PhoneDirectory5 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        **PhoneRecord[] records= new PhoneRecord[1];
        int numRecords = 0;**

        // Display list of commands
        System.out.println("Phone directory commands: \n" +
                " a - Add a new phone number\n" +
                " f - Find a new phone number\n" +
                " q - Quit\n" +
                " d - Delete record\n");

        // Read and execute commands
        while (true) {

            // Prompt user to enter a command
            SimpleIO.prompt("Enter command (a, f, d, or q): ");
            String command = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();

            // Determine whether command is "a", "f", "q", or
            // illegal. Execute command if illegal.
            **if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))** {

                // Command is "a". prompt user for name and number,
                // then create a phone record and store it in the
                // database.
                **if (numRecords < records.length) {
                    SimpleIO.prompt("Enter a new name: ");
                    String name = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
                    SimpleIO.prompt("Enter new phone number: ");
                    String number = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
                    records[numRecords] =
                            new PhoneRecord(name, number);
                    numRecords++;
                } else if (numRecords == records.length) {
                    PhoneRecord[] newRecords = new PhoneRecord[records.length*2];
                    System.arraycopy(records, 0, newRecords, 0, records.length);
                    SimpleIO.prompt("Enter a new name: ");
                    String name = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
                    SimpleIO.prompt("Enter new phone number: ");
                    String number = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
                    newRecords[numRecords] =
                            new PhoneRecord(name, number);
                    numRecords++;**
                } else
                    System.out.println("Sorry, database is full.");

            } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {

                // Command is "f". Prompt user for search key.
                // Search the database for records whose name begins
                // with the search key. Print these names and the
                // corresponding phone numbers.
                SimpleIO.prompt("Enter name to look up: ");
                String key = SimpleIO.readLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++) {
                    String name = records[i].getName().toLowerCase();
                    if (name.startsWith(key)) {
                        System.out.println(records[i].getName() + " " +
                                records[i].getNumber());
                        break;
                    } else if (i == numRecords - 1)
                        System.out.println("Sorry, your search did not" +
                                " match any records.");
                }
            } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
                SimpleIO.prompt("Enter the name of the record to delete: ");
                String key = SimpleIO.readLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++) {
                    String name = records[i].getName().toLowerCase();
                    if (name.startsWith(key)) {
                        records[i] = new PhoneRecord("", "");
                        break;
                    } else if (i == numRecords - 1)
                        System.out.println("Sorry, your search did not match" +
                                " any records.");
                }

            } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                // Command is "q".. Terminate program
                System.out.println("You have elected to exit the phone directory.");
                return;

            } else {
                // Command is illegal. Display error message.
                System.out.println("Command was not recognized; " +
                        "please enter only a, f, d or q.");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

// Represents a record containing a name and a phone number
class PhoneRecord {
    private String name;
    private String number;

    // Constructor
    public PhoneRecord(String personName, String phoneNumber) {
        name = personName;
        number = phoneNumber;
    }

    // Returns the name stored in the record
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // Returns the phone number stored in the record
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

All this being said, when I allocated new array space in this fashion...

```
else if (numRecords == records.length) {
                    PhoneRecord[] newRecords = new PhoneRecord[records.length*2];
                    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
                        newRecords[i] = records[i];
                    records = newRecords;
                    SimpleIO.prompt("Enter a new name: ");
                    String name = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
                    SimpleIO.prompt("Enter new phone number: ");
                    String number = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
                    newRecords[numRecords] =
                            new PhoneRecord(name, number);
                    numRecords++;
```

...the program did exactly what I needed it to do, namely, double the size of the array with each user entry and never print the *"Sorry, but the database is full"* message. My question is, why can't I get the program to work with the *.arraycopy* method? Any help would be much appreciated.

When I do this...

```
else if (numRecords == records.length) {
                    PhoneRecord[] newRecords = new PhoneRecord[records.length*2];
                    System.arraycopy(records, 0, newRecords, 0, records.length);
                    **newRecords = records;**
                    SimpleIO.prompt("Enter a new name: ");
                    String name = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
                    SimpleIO.prompt("Enter new phone number: ");
                    String number = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
                    newRecords[numRecords] =
                            new PhoneRecord(name, number);
                    numRecords++;
```

...is when I get the arrayindexoutofbounds error.

Comment: Would be ArrayList not a lot easier to use ?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't know what an ArrayList is. I'm an absolute novice.

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: Yes, it is, and ok, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays have a fixed length in Java. If you want a dynamic-length array, rather than programming it from scratch, you should use the one given for you in the standard API : java.util.ArrayList. Look at its documentation here : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html. This class is part of the Java collections API, which is a must-know for any Java programmer. Learn to use them in the [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Rather than a `PhoneRecord[]`, you would have a list of `PhoneRecord`s :

```
List<PhoneRecord> records = new ArrayList<PhoneRecord>();
```

You can add a new record with

```
records.add(newRecord);
```

and the array wrapped by the array list will automatically grow if needed.

And you can access to a specific index with

```
PhoneRecord record = records.get(index);
```

You can also iterate on the list as you would with an array :

```
for (PhoneRecord record : records) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks JB, that is something I will definitely be familiarizing myself with in the coming weeks. But, just to sate my curiosity, why doesn't this particular programmed doubling array work, when it worked with a for loop? It just doesn't make sense to me. I read the documentation on .arraycopy, these twin pairs of code should be doing the same thing, except I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: For every iteration, you'll never get indexOutOfBound because you created a new bigger array to store the new record. But the problem is, you didn't assign the newRecord array back to the records variable. So, records.length is always 1. When numRecords is greater than 1, it'll print db is full.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign newRecords back to records in the System.arraycopy example.

edit: I agree with JB Nizet. You should use ArrayList instead.

Comment: Yes, but when I do, I get the "arrayindexoutofbounds". As written above, the machine merely skips the "else if" altogether after the second user input and prints the" Sorry, but database is full" message, meaning numRecords has exceeded records.length, which it is not supposed to do. In short, I can't figure out why numRecords exceeds records.length, which happens when I use the .arraycopy method, regardless of whether I assign newRecords to records or not.

Comment: No, you didn't.
You should have a line:-
    `records = newRecords;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the easiest way to get around this is creating a try/catch for the exception. When exception comes in you create the new array. if you cant get the arraycopy to work you can always make a loop to copy elements from old array to new one.

Comment: Never ever use exception handling for program flow control. Exceptions are for exceptions and not to fix code that i don´t understand.